# Created two tables in Latex, but they're spread far apart . How do I move them closer together so there isn't so much blank space?

Tags: tables, floats, vertical-alignment, colortbl

```
\begin{document}
\textbf{2b. }
\definecolor{Cyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
p & q & r & $\neg p$ & $\neg q$ & $\neg r$ & $p \vee r$ & $p \vee q$ & $\neg q \vee \neg r$ & $(p \vee r) \wedge (p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)$ \\
\hline
\rowcolor{Cyan}
T & T & T & F & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
T & T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
F & T & T & T & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
F & T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T & F\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
F & F & T & T & T & F & T & F & T & F\\
F & F & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & F\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
$ (q \wedge r)$ & $\neg (q \wedge r)$ & $p \wedge \neg (q \wedge r)$\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
T & F & F\\
F & T & T\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
F & T &T\\
F & T &T\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
T & F &F\\
F & T &F\\
\rowcolor{Cyan}
F & T & F\\
F & T & F\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Are these two tables all in your file? Since the arrangement of LaTeX depends on the space left on a page, it matters if there are other texts.

Comment: You don't seem to be putting a `\caption` on your table (unless that's the purpose of **2b**, in which case you should read up on how to caption a table).  If there's no caption, there's no reason they need to be in separate `table` environments (or in a `table` environment at all).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/107497

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. When I complete your document, I don't get the space that you see, so without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) not sure how to help here.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the two `tabular` environments to be typeset independently of and possibly quite far from each other, don't place them in separate `table` environments. Instead, just insert an instruction such as `\vspace{1cm}` (or whatever other distance suits your needs) between the two `tabular` environments.

Incidentally, doesn't the first `tabular` environment contain just 10 columns, instead of the 13 columns indicated by your code? Now, it's generally the case that indicating more than the required number of columns doesn't immediately generate an error or warning message -- or even necessarily mess up the appearance of the tabular material right away. I'd still avoid overstating the number of columns, though, as providing incorrect numbers of columns can sometimes lead to puzzling bugs that are tedious to track down.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Cyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcommand\rcC{\rowcolor{Cyan}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt} % <-- new (default value: 6pt)
\centering % <-- new

\begin{tabular}{ | *{10}{c|} } % Not 13, but 10 columns, right?
\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $r$ & $\neg p$ & $\neg q$ & $\neg r$ & 
$p \vee r$ & $p \vee q$ & $\neg q \vee \neg r$ & 
\medmuskip=3mu  % <-- new (default value: 4mu)
$(p \vee r) \wedge (p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)$ \\
\hline
\rcC
T & T & T & F & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
T & T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T\\
\rcC
T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
\rcC
F & T & T & T & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
F & T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T & F\\
\rcC
F & F & T & T & T & F & T & F & T & F\\
F & F & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & F\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
%\begin{table}

\vspace{5mm} % or whatever length value suits your needs

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
$ (q \wedge r)$ & $\neg (q \wedge r)$ & $p \wedge \neg (q \wedge r)$\\
\hline
\rcC
T & F & F\\
F & T & T\\
\rcC
F & T &T\\
F & T &T\\
\rcC
T & F &F\\
F & T &F\\
\rcC
F & T & F\\
F & T & F\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to nice @Mico answer (+1). In your particular case, when all columns are of the same type (`c`), with use table package `tabularray` you not need to care about number of columns. They will automatically adopted to content of table body.

Beside this, you can color rows (again automatically) by `row{even} = {bg=Cyan}` and also put first table row into math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Cyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering % <-- new
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}={solid},vlines,
            cells = {c},
            colsep = {4.4pt},
            row{1} = {mode=math},
            row{even} = {bg=Cyan}
            }
p & q & r & \neg p & \neg q & \neg r
    & p \vee r & p \vee q & \neg q \vee \neg r
    & (p \vee r) \wedge (p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r) \\
T & T & T & F & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
T & T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
F & T & T & T & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
F & T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T & F\\
F & F & T & T & T & F & T & F & T & F\\
F & F & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & F\\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip 
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}={solid},vlines,
            cells = {c},
            colsep = {4.4pt},
            row{1} = {mode=math},
            row{even} = {bg=Cyan}
            }
 (q \wedge r)
    & \neg (q \wedge r)
        & p \wedge \neg (q \wedge r)\\
T   & F & F\\
F   & T & T\\
F   & T & T\\
F   & T & T\\
T   & F & F\\
F   & T & F\\
F   & T & F\\
F   & T & F\\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The such a way of  "zebra" coloring of tables you can achieve at "classic" table too. Before table you only need to insert:

```
\rowcolors{2}{white}{Cyan}
```

and than remove all `\rowcolor{Cyan}` commands in table body.